# Open pdf file failed

Tags: c#, pdf, process, adobe

I want to open a pdf file with Adobe Reader. I used this code shown here, but it doesn't open it. I do see the Adobe Acrobt Reader in the proccess list in Task Manager, but it does not show the window with my PDF file:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(AdobPath);
startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false; ;
startInfo.Arguments = string.Format("/A \"page={0}\" \"{1}\"", pn, PdfPath);                    

Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();

if (process.HasExited == false)
    process.WaitForExit(10000);

process.Close();
```

Comment: Try setting `startInfo.UseShellExecute=false;`

Comment: @dcg I tried that but i still that problem.i see the adob in proccess list in task manager .but i don't khow why it don't show me window